# How to search keyword as ignore case in spring data solr?

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I need to search key word with ignore case and containing keyword with method name using spring data solr. like this

`Page<SolrModel>findByNameIgnoreCaseAndContaining(@Boost(2) String name, Pageable pageable);`

but its not working. It working like this

`Page<SolrModel>findByNameIgnoreCase(@Boost(2) String name, Pageable pageable);`.

and like this 
`Page<SolrModel>findByNameContaining(@Boost(2) String name, Pageable pageable);`.

But i need find key word using ignore case and containing both, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you reverse `containing` and `ignorecase` and remove the `and`:

```
Page<SolrModel> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(@Boost(2) String name, Pageable pageable);
```